# Java getResourceAsStream cannot load resource

Tags: resources, classpath, loading

I am trying to load a class whose name is specified in a properties file. Here is the code for the same.

```
try {
    Properties properties = new Properties();   
    InputStream in = MyAbstractFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("/some.properties");
    properties.load(in);
    String impl = properties.getProperty("key");
    MyAbstractFactory factories = (MyAbstractFactory) Class.forName( impl ).newInstance();
    return factories;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return new DefaultFactoriesImpl();
}
```

This code is part of a jar file. the properties file is just outside the jar. Its unable to load the properties file and is loading DefaultFactoriesImpl instead. I know this happens when MyAbstractFactory.class.getResourceAsStream cant find the resource in the class path but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Dir Structure:-

- com
- myjar.jar
- some.properties

Command i am executing is "java -jar myjar.jar"

Any feedback on why this might be happening. Could this have something to do with Clasloaders? I'd like to add that when i run this code from within eclipse it seems pick up some.properties just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading slash from the argument you pass to `getResourceAsStream()`.

Put the folder outside the JAR into the CLASSPATH when you execute the JAR.  I don't know if the manifest CLASSPATH overrides the one you might pass using -cp.  Play with it; one of them will work.

It's not finding your .properties file because it's not in the JVM CLASSPATH.  When you do it properly, the JVM will find it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Removing leading slash will append the current package name which doesn't seem to be the right thing to do. When i try to unzip the jar file and run it i get some "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Code segment has wrong length in class file" on one of the class files i have implemented. Not sure if these are related issues!

Comment: Anyway, what i am facing now seems to be a different issue. So yes, running it using java -classpath .;myjar.jar com.fullyqualified.MainClass seemed to pick up properties file correctly.